# JodaTime and Daylight saving time

Tags: android, kotlin, jodatime, java-time, android-jodatime

I develop a custom schedule calendar, with 30 minutes gap, so when i generetae this by adding 30 minutes:

```
date = date.plusMinutes(minuteStep)
```

so in moment when our time zone switch to Daylight saving time, jodatime add 1 hour to current time and in this case my schedule got broken, it's posibile to exclude this offset?. Thank's

example:

```
2021-03-28T00:00:00.000+02:00
2021-03-28T00:30:00.000+02:00
2021-03-28T01:00:00.000+02:00
2021-03-28T01:30:00.000+02:00
```

and just after this i got:

```
2021-03-28T03:00:00.000+03:00
```

Comment: I think your schedule is not broken. Instead, it considers there is no 2 am at that very day (when daylight saving makes one hour disappear, the clock goes from 1:59 am directly to 3 am).

Comment: Well, if you really want to ignore the offset, use a `java.time.LocalDateTime` (don't know if there's an equivalent in JodaTime).

Comment: But half an hour after 01:30 it *was* 03:00. Are you saying that you want to schedule non-existing times? Why?

Comment: @deHaar As the answer says, there is a like-named equivalent to `java.time.LocalDateTime` in `org.joda.time.LocalDateTime`.

Comment: Or to ask differently: What *precisely* is your desired output? Please give both time and UTC offset for each desired output time (if I understand correctly that you want both).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using `org.joda.time.DateTime` which is the wrong class for this requirement. The right class for this requirement would be `org.joda.time.LocalDate`.

`org.joda.time.LocalTime` is useful for representing human-based date-time, such as movie times, or the opening and closing times of the local library, or to create a digital clock etc. `LocalDateTime`, a combination of LocalDate with LocalTime, can be used to represent a specific event, such as the first race for the Louis Vuitton Cup Finals in America's Cup Challenger Series, which began at 1:10 p.m. on August 17, 2013. Note that this means 1:10 p.m. in local time. ([Source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/datetime.html))

Switching to `org.joda.time.LocalDate` should fix the issue. However, check the following notice at the [Home Page of Joda-Time](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/)

> Joda-Time is the de facto standard date and time library for Java
> prior to Java SE 8. Users are now asked to migrate to java.time
> (JSR-310).

Therefore, I suggest you switch to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> . You can learn about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>